# How to set CacheHeaders when Script is loaded with GWT ScriptInjector?

Tags: java, javascript, caching, gwt

I use the GWT [ScriptInjector](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html) to inject an external JavaScript file like this:

```
ScriptInjector.fromUrl("http://example.com/foo.js").setCallback(
     new Callback() {
        public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
          Window.alert("Script load failed.");
        }
        public void onSuccess(Void result) {
          Window.alert("Script load success.");
        }
     }).inject();
```

This works fine but not expires header is set, i.e., the browser does not cache this script.

**Is it possible to set a header for the ScriptInjector to cache the external js file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set headers on a resource that you do not control. Most likely, the owner of this script already set headers to allow caching if this script does not change often.

If you do control this file, however (i.e. this script is on your server), you set the headers the same way that you do on any other static resource.